# VBA: Copying a range (row-by-row) in a loop and inserting this (row-by-row) in a new sheet (loop + if statement)

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement, range, copy-paste

In VBA I try to run a loop with an if statement. The loop is set to run a row at a time for a range (wks "Data", B7:J25).

For each row if the value at column C7:C25 is 1, I would like to copy that row (e.g. B7:J7) and insert it at the worksheet "temp" one at a time.

I have tried various codes, for example:

```
Sub start()
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim wsData, wsCalcAndOutput, wsTemp As Worksheet
      For i = 1 To 25
         If Cells((7 + i), 3) = "1" Then
         Worksheets("Data").Range("B7:J7").Copy _
         Worksheets("temp").Range("B7:J7")
         End If
      Next
End Sub
```

But then I can only copy and paste the first row of the range. Alternatively, I found this procedure at stackoverflow, but I can't seem to be able to paste what I copy at each iteration:

Dim wsData, wsCalcAndOutput As Worksheet
Dim rSPX, rSX5E, rNKY, rUKX, rSMI, rEEMUP, testData As Range

```
Sub start()
   Dim i As Integer

   For i = 1 To 25
         If Cells((7 + i), 3) = "1" Then
              With ActiveSheet
               .Range(.Cells((7 + i), 2), .Cells((7 + i), 10)).Copy
              End With
         End If
   Next

End Sub
```

Is this the right way to do so or is there a more efficient way?

Also - in the dataset the criteria for the if statement is actually a string called either "TRUE" or "FALSE". Can an if statement use a string as a signal instead of "1"?

All the best, 
Christoffer

Comment: Don't copy in a loop. Filter, and then copy visible cells. The macro recorder might be helpful here. Or use Advanced Filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BigBen says, using AutoFilter would be quicker but here is one way of doing this with a loop. Have added a few comments which hopefully explain the basics.

One problem with your code was that you weren't changing the destination cells so they would continually be overwritten.

```
Sub start()

Dim i As Long 'better than integer
Dim n As Long: n = 7
Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsCalcAndOutput As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet 'specify each type

With Worksheets("Data")
    For i = 7 To 25 'change as appropriate
        If .Cells(i, 3) = 1 Then 'no need for quotes
            Range(.Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "J")).Copy _
                    Worksheets("temp").Cells(n, "B") 'start at row 7?
            n = n + 1 'update so that we don't overwrite next time
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```